# Was Kolmorogov really inspired to publish Foundations of the theory of probability because he needed money to repair his dacha?

Tags: mathematics, mathematicians, biographical-details, probability, kolmogorov

#### Background

It is well known that Kolmogorov published in 1933 his ground-breaking work on probability theory *Grundbegriffe der Wahrscheinlichkeitsrechnung* usually known to English speakers as *Foundations of the theory of probability*.

Numerous sources also claim that much of his mathematical discussion and work took place in his dacha at Komarovka a small village outside Moscow.

#### My question

I am sure I remember reading many years ago that he was inspired to write the monograph because the roof of his dacha needed repairing. This is such a strange story that I cannot imagine I made it up but it may, of course, be an urban legend. Can anyone confirm this either way?

#### My research

I have done internet searches for Kolmogorov dacha, and for Kolmogorov Komarovka without finding anything which adds much to what I summarise above. I also tried Kolmogorow Datsche in case there was anything in German, the language of the monograph. I am afraid my grasp of Russian is non-existent. Adding roof to the search or Dach to the searches just adds people anxious to quote me for the repair of my roof.

Comment: According to https://homepages.cwi.nl/~paulv/papers/kolmogorov.pdf , he published the paper in 1933 and bought the dacha in 1935.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://homepages.cwi.nl/~paulv/KOLMOGOROV.BIOGRAPHY.html)?

Comment: @kimchilover do you want to post that as an answer so I can accept it and close the thread?

Comment: @mdewey No.  Something has come up that makes this inconvenient for me. Why don't you write up the answer, or edit your question to fit the new evidence.

Comment: This question reminds me of a quote by Michael Caine concerning his appearance in the awful 1987 movie Jaws: The Revenge. He said “I have never seen it, but by all accounts it is terrible. However, I have seen the house that it built, and it is terrific.”

Answer (score 2):

User kimchi lover noted in a comment that this can be answered from the article

[https://homepages.cwi.nl/~paulv/papers/kolmogorov.pdf](https://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Epaulv/papers/kolmogorov.pdf)

The relevant text is
"In 1935, Kolmogorov and Aleksandrov acquired (initially part of) an old manor house at Komarovka [the former Stanislavskii dacha], with room for a large library and several guests. "

Authored by Paul M. B. Vitányi and translated by Harold H Mc Fadden the article entitled "Remembering Kolmogorov" was published in Metascience (2011) 20:509–511 DOI 10.1007/s11016-011-9540-6. In it we find that Kolmogorov and his friend Aleksandrov only purchased (part of) the dacha in 1935 so obviously my memory must be a false one since by then *Grundbegriffe der Wahrscheinlichkeitsrechnung* was already two years in the past.

User Rodrigo de Azevedo also pointed out this fact.